# Visual Foxpro Array [] or ( )

Tags: arrays, visual-foxpro

In a Visual Foxpro application one of the users get an error (the rest doesn't). And i believe its because arrays are used in the form of arr(number) instead of arr[number] . Does anyone know what causes this strange behavior at a single user?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no difference between using [] and ().  They can be use interchangeably.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Either use of array references is valid as long as its properly balanced as () or [].  The problem is probably upstream where the array is getting declared or prepared.  I've had to debug historically strange instances like this where one user was going about a process in a totally different way than others, and the business work flow...  Anyhow, because of some "bypassed" process, the array wasn't getting created and thus forced a failure.

Does it always crash at the same location in the process?

I would strongly encourage some error trapping in the process for this "one" user.  Worse comes to worse, I would put something in the area of the code something like...

```
if atc( "PersonsLoginName", sys(0)) > 0
   TurnOnMyCustomDebugging()   && for this special scenario trapping
endif
```

Additionally, I don't know what you have for error trapping routines, but I'd get a dump of memory at the time of the error and the full call stack that got the user to that point.  If you need help on that, let me know too.

Answer (score 1):

Foxpro does not differentiate between the two.  This is actually documented in both the [DIMENSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76zh59sz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [DECLARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48z2300b%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) commands' remarks.

In fact, the documentation doesn't strictly follow one way or another.  The DIMENSION and DECLARE commands define the syntax with parenthesis ().

```
DIMENSION ArrayName1(nRows1 [, nColumns1]) [AS cType]
   [, ArrayName2(nRows2 [, nColumns2])] ...
```

But the example provided in the [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awcwf6ee%28VS.80%29.aspx) section of the documentation uses brackets [].

```
DIMENSION ArrayName[5,2]
ArrayName[1,2] = 966789
```

Comment: The documentation is strictly following a convension in that things between `[]`s are optional parameters, this is nothing to do with the question really.

Comment: @rudi_visser Please read over that again. If you look at the declaration - ignoring the optional parameters, it uses parens. Then, if you look at the example, it uses square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why this question was "bumped" from 2010. Maybe because it is kind of "VFP basics" and need details?

Answers are already good. [] and () could be used. It is primarily a preference.

VFP actually doesn't even care if the name denotes and array. It might be a function accepting one or two integer parameters (1..N). However, if there is an array in scope then it takes precedence. 
Example:

```
Dimension Dummy[10]
? Dummy[5]    && prints .F. - array members are not initialized
Dummy[2] = 6  && sets array member
? Dummy[2]    && prints 6
Release Dummy && array variable released

? Dummy[5]    && prints 10 - procedure is called
* Dummy[2] = 6  && error - variable does not exists
? Dummy[2]    && prints 4 - procedure is called

Procedure Dummy(tnDim1)
   Return m.tnDim1 * 2
endproc
```

It wouldn't matter if you used [] or () for an array or function (or procedure - in VFP procedure and function also has no difference, both accept parameters and return result).

As per the OP question, a single user wouldn't have a different result just because [] or () used.